# Bruteforce hash with start-up character

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, hash, brute-force

I made a script to bruteforce hash, this script is functional only. I'm looking for an algorithm that allows to start the bruteforce where it was stopped. For example I stop the bruteforce at the list of character `"abcde"`, I would have to specify it so that it restarts the bruteforce from `"abcde"` so that it does not have to start again from `0`. Do you have an idea of how to do it?

```
import hashlib
import time

from itertools import chain, product

class Hashing:
    def __init__(self, hashing: str, algorithm: str, character_type: list, item: list, start_char: str = None):
        self.character = {'letter': 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'number': '0123456789', 'maj': 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'space': ' ', 'speciaux': """<>&é"'(-è_çà)=ù!:;,+%§/.?*µ~#}{[|`\^@]¤"""}
        self.character_type = character_type
        self.combinaison_number = 0
        self.algorithm = algorithm
        self.start_char = start_char
        self.item = item
        self.hashing = hashing
        self.result = None
        self.go = False
        self.extend = ""

    def bruteforce(self, charset, maxlength):
        return (''.join(candidate)
            for candidate in chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat=i)
            for i in range(self.item[0], maxlength + 1)))

    def start(self):
        for i in self.character_type:
            self.extend += self.character.get(i)
        if self.algorithm == "md5":
            self.algo_md5()
        elif self.algorithm == "sha256":
            self.algo_sha256()

    def algo_md5(self):
        self.time = time.time()
        for attempt in self.bruteforce(self.extend, self.item[1]):
            self.combinaison_number +=1
            if hashlib.md5(attempt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == self.hashing:
                self.print_result(self, attempt)
                break

    def algo_sha256(self):
        self.time = time.time()
        for attempt in self.bruteforce(self.extend, self.item[1]):
            self.combinaison_number +=1
            if hashlib.sha256(attempt.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() == self.hashing:
                self.print_result(self, attempt)
                break
        
    def print_result(self, *attempt):
        print(f"The result is `{attempt[1]}` with {self.combinaison_number} test\n{self.combinaison_number/(time.time()-self.time)} test in 1 secondes")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Hash = Hashing("3ed7dceaf266cafef032b9d5db224717", "md5", ['letter', 'number'], [1, 10])
    Hash.start()
```

Comment: You could treat the alphabet as a numeric system (like binary, decimal, hexadecimal etc) and convert the current `self.combinaison_number` to a "number" in that numeric system, so the next `attempt`

Comment: How do you intend to stop or interrupt the bruteforce at some point (much less restart it)?

Comment: Currently I am killing the process, but I will change that later

Comment: I do not understand what you advise me (sorry) to do, what is the use of converting my letters into hexadecimal characters @ForceBru

Comment: @Jourdelune, hexadecimal was just an example of a non-decimal numeric system. You have a one-to-one correspondence between the (decimal) _number_ of a combination and the combination itself, where the next combination is essentially `previous_combination + 1`, like `"aa" + 1 = "ab"`. Thus, it's a kind of numeric system. Thus, you can convert the position of a combination (like combination #1234) to the combination itself, like `"abba"`. It's something I used in one of my early projects when I was just starting programming. There may be better solutions, but this one worked really well.